# Importance of a theorem of Chevalley

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, soft-question

There is the following Theorem of Chevalley:

> Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a finite-type reduced $k$-algebra. Then for any $\mathfrak p\in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ the ring $\hat{A_{\mathfrak p}}$ is reduced.

I would like to learn why this theorem is important, and how it is related to other results. Is it important because it shows that $\mathrm{Spec}(\hat{A_{\mathfrak p}})$ is a variety "in the classical sense"?

Comment: The next in line is surely, Zariski's main theorem, which says that for a normal local domain, the completion is also a (normal) domain. The importance of ZMT can not be over stressed.

Comment: @Mohan thanks for your comment!